# Can I have several different port listeners on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I`m using OpenShift Online hosting for my backend. But I can not register several port listeners. I get the error: EADDRINUSE
I need one service part to run on a specific port, and another part (expressJS) on another port

Comment: Please include some snippets of the code you are using to bind to the ports.

Comment: Can I use any other ports to connect to my backend except OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT?

Comment: According to the [user guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Binding_Applications_to_Ports.html), ports 15000 - 35530 are available for binding internal IP. The only externally addressable port for HTTP or [Web Socket](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html) connectivity (through 80, 443, 8000, 8443) would be the `$OPENSHIFT_cartName_PORT` though.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly it`s not possible?